# ExtJS Tooltip is not hiding on mouseout

Tags: extjs

I am able to create a tooltip on mouseover, but on mouseout my tooltip is not destroying or hiding.

I am using the below code. Please suggest the corrections.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-classic/resources/theme-classic-all.css" 
         rel = "stylesheet" />
      <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>

      <script type = "text/javascript">
         Ext.onReady(function() {
            toolTip = new Ext.ToolTip ({       
               id : 'toolTip',
               html : 'This is a basic toolTip'
            });
            Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
               renderTo: Ext.getElementById('buttonId'),
               text: 'Hover Me',

               listeners: {
                  mouseover: function() {
                     toolTip.show();
                  }
               }
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "buttonId"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't have any code hiding the toolTip, unless you are, and simply didn't supply that code?

Comment: Why don't you use the `tooltip` property for the button?

Comment: @PeterAbolins, If I add a mouseout listener, mouseover and mouseout is being called repeatedly one after another and user is not able to see tooltip. and I don't want add closable attribute for this tooptip. Please suggest if you have a better solution. My Requirement is hover-text should disappear on mouse out

Comment: I don't know why people downvote very quickly.

Comment: @MasterPo, I really very thankful to you. after your suggetion i tried the below code and its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-classic/resources/theme-classic-all.css" 
         rel = "stylesheet" />
      <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>

      <script type = "text/javascript">
         Ext.onReady(function() {



            new Ext.button.Button({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text: 'Click',
    tooltip: 'Tooltip',
    tooltipType: 'title'
});
         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "buttonId"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```